# Get content of tag by class name

Tags: php, dom

I need to get span content from external url.
I managed to created a script working fine but not with the url i need, the result show the loading icon.

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.ryanair.com/fr/fr/booking/home/CRL/RAK/2019-03-24/2019-03-28/1/0/0/0');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$node = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'flights-table-price__price')]");
print_r($doc->saveHTML($node->item(0)));
```

Comment: what does that link to phpfiddle represent?

Comment: I can't find `.flights-table-price__price` in target page

Comment: Check this screenshot : https://ibb.co/W6R9hmv

Comment: If you check https://www.ryanair.com/fr/fr/booking/home/CRL/RAK/2019-03-24/2019-03-28/1/0/0/0 using View Source instead of the inspector, you see that the element is not present. It's added with javascript (page is using angular), so you won't find it inside $html. You should find a way to run all the code on your server to be able to get that content.

Comment: Any idea how to do that ? (the website can't even be loaded in iframe)